# locate + grep variable in bash function

Tags: bash, function, grep, zshrc

zsh: *4.3.17*
GNU bash: *4.2.24*
GNU grep: *2.10*

I would like to know what I did wrong in the `grep` part -> why `grep` doesn't highlight the results when used inside the `.zshrc` file, actually it doesn't output something at all.
When not using a variable or a .rc file (testing the cmd on the cli), `grep` works like expected.

```
function seek() { clear; echo $1; locate -ie "$PWD${1}" | grep "${1}"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is $GREP_COLORS set early enough in the .rc file? Also, you can try `grep --color=always` if you are piping the output of grep through something.

Comment: The weird thing is that there is no output at all. When replacing `${1}` in the .rc file with `[my search pattern]` (hard coding) everything works fine.